# How to find child element in React using onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I am triggering Click event as below and I want to access the child element '.details'. Please suggest how to achieve that, I want to apply color to the child node '.details' when clicking parent .movie

```
return (
  <div className="movie" onClick={e => this.selectMovie(e)}>
    <div className="floatleft">
      <img alt={Title} src={Poster} />
    </div>
    <div className="floaright">
      <h3>{Title}</h3>
      Year : <b>{Year}</b>
      <br />
      <br />
      Director : <b>{Director}</b>
      <br />
      Production : <b>{Production}</b>
      <br />
      <br />
      Actor : <b>{Actors}</b>
      <br />
      <br />
      Released : <b>{Released}</b>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div className="details">
      =============
      {Runtime}
      {imdbRating}
    </div>
  </div>
);

selectMovie = e => {
  console.log(e);
  //console.log(data)
  //event.currentTarget.find('.details').style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
};
```

Comment: Hi, what's wrong with your code, does it throw an error or just doing nothing? Have you tried with just : onClick={this.selectMovie}

Comment: In react it's generally better to try and avoid modifying or traversing the DOM yourself, what is the end goal of this? If you're just setting the background colour, this could be done using state much more reliably.

Comment: I want to set background color for the child node when clicking the parent node

Comment: I can't see enough of your code to give a proper example, but you should be able to use state and a simple boolean for whether the child is coloured (Using inline styles or a class on the rendered element), which can be toggled by your click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ref` for this:

```
this.detailsRef = React.createRef(); // ---- in constructor
........
// assign it here
<div class="details" ref={this.detailsRef}
```

Now you can use `this.detailsRef` to get the element and work with it:

```
selectMovie = e => {
  console.log(e);
  //console.log(data)
  //event.currentTarget.find('.details').style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
  this.detailsRef.current.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';//<-------------this one here
};
```

Answer (score 3):

it's not recommended, you can use state and based on that you should add class or dynamic style like this.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isSelected: false
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="movie" onClick={e => this.selectMovie(e)}>
        <div className="floatleft">
          <img alt={Title} src={Poster} />
        </div>
        <div className="floaright">
          <h3>{Title}</h3>
          Year : <b>{Year}</b>
          <br />
          <br />
          Director : <b>{Director}</b>
          <br />
          Production : <b>{Production}</b>
          <br />
          <br />
          Actor : <b>{Actors}</b>
          <br />
          <br />
          Released : <b>{Released}</b>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div className="details" style={isSelected ? { backgroundColor: '#ccc'} : {}}>
          =============
          {Runtime}
          {imdbRating}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  selectMovie = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({ isSelected: true });
  };
}
```

Good practice would also be to make this a `<button></button>` element instead of a div. If you have additional functionalities, like submitting something when clicking this, use `<form></form>`

```
  <button className="movie" onClick={e => this.selectMovie(e)}>
    <div className="floatleft">
      <img alt={Title} src={Poster} />
    </div>
    <div className="floaright">
      <h3>{Title}</h3>
      Year : <b>{Year}</b>
      <br />
      <br />
      Director : <b>{Director}</b>
      <br />
      Production : <b>{Production}</b>
      <br />
      <br />
      Actor : <b>{Actors}</b>
      <br />
      <br />
      Released : <b>{Released}</b>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div className="details" style={isSelected ? { backgroundColor: '#ccc'} : {}}>
      =============
      {Runtime}
      {imdbRating}
    </div>
  </button>
```